# JBoss under Win Server 2008 with OpenCV 2.4.2

Tags: java, opencv, jboss, windows-server-2008-r2, javacv

I've got a application running under JBoss 5.1.x and Windows Server 2008. This app, need OpenCV 2.4.2.

My files of opencv are stored at c:\opencv , javacv are stored at c:\javacv.

I added the paths of libs to the environment variables but i've got the next error.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\adminyb\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp15302835286\jniopencv_core.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

how i can solve this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a little bit late, but we had the same problem and didn't find any answer over the internet, so this could help someone in the future.

The problem is connected with a missing dll in Window 2008 Server, we solve it copying this dll "msvcp100.dll" under our %JAVA%/jre7/bin folder

Hope this help

Comment: Finally, i solved it setting correctly the opencv path in the variable PATH of system.